# pass filtered listview item to next activity

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Here i am using using BaseAdapter to filter my listview items.when without using search option if i click on my listview item the listView.setOnItemClickListener works well, I mean the item at the clicked position is passed to next activity.But on the filtered result if i click on the item,some other data is passed to next activity..what might be the issue.?can anyone please help me to solve this issue..?

---

**Activity**

```
public class BindTenGPS extends Activity {
    private MenuItem menuItem;
    DbaAdapter db;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ListView listView ;
    EditText inputSearch;
    private  BindTenDeviceBaseAdapter adapter;
    List<RowTenDevice> rowTenDevice;
    ArrayList<String> DeviceName = new ArrayList<String>();

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.list1_main);
         inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
         db=new DbaAdapter(getApplicationContext());
         new LoadTrackNumbers().execute();

     }

     private class LoadTrackNumbers extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
            int myProgress;
            @Override  
            protected void onPreExecute()  
            {  
                //Create a new progress dialog  
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BindTenGPS.this);  
                //Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar  
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);  
                //Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'  
                progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");  
                //Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please wait...'  
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading application View, please wait...");  
                //This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key  
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);  
                //This dialog isn't indeterminate  
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);  
                //The maximum number of items is 100  
                progressDialog.setMax(100);  
                //Set the current progress to zero  
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);  
                //Display the progress dialog  
                progressDialog.show(); 

            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try  
                {  
                    //Get the current thread's token  
                    synchronized (this)  
                    { 
                        DeviceName.clear();
                        publishProgress(10);
                        this.wait(500);
                        Connection conn = null;
                        try {
                            Log.w("Error connection","shyam1");
                        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
                        Log.w("Error connection","shyam2");
                        Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example0.");
                        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                        Log.w("Error connection","shyam3");
                        String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip address;instance=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=AAUMConnect;";
                        String username = "username";
                        String password = "password";
                        Log.w("Error connection","shyam4");
                        publishProgress(20);
                        this.wait(500);
                        publishProgress(30);
                        this.wait(500);
                        publishProgress(40);
                        this.wait(500);
                        publishProgress(50);
                        this.wait(500);
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
                        publishProgress(80);
                        Log.w("Error connection","shyam5");
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet reset;
                        db.open();
                        int superuser = db.GetISSuperUser();
                        db.close();
                        db.open();
                        int clientid = db.GetClientID();
                        db.close();
                        if(superuser == 0)
                        {
                            db.open();
                            String branch = db.GetBranch();
                            db.close();
                            reset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT dbo.fn_AddEveryNthItem(LEFT(AssignVehicleToTrackTable, LEN(AssignVehicleToTrackTable) - 1), ',','@', 1) AS DeviceName FROM (SELECT DeviceName + ',' FROM AssignVehicleToTrack where ClientID = " + clientid + " and BranchName = '" + branch.trim() + "' and VirtualNo = 'GPS' order by DeviceName FOR XML PATH ('')) T1 (AssignVehicleToTrackTable)");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT dbo.fn_AddEveryNthItem(LEFT(AssignVehicleToTrackTable, LEN(AssignVehicleToTrackTable) - 1), ',','@', 1) AS DeviceName FROM (SELECT DeviceName + ',' FROM AssignVehicleToTrack where ClientID = " + clientid + " and VirtualNo = 'GPS' order by DeviceName FOR XML PATH ('')) T1 (AssignVehicleToTrackTable)");
                        }

                        //Print the data to the console
                        Log.w("Error connection","shyam6");
                        int i1 = 0, c = 0;
                         try
                         {
                             while(reset.next()){
                                    publishProgress(c);
                                    String[] tokens = new String[100];
                                    tokens = reset.getString(1).split("@");
                                    for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
                                    {
                                        DeviceName.add(tokens[i].substring(1));
                                    }
                                    i1++;
                                    c+=10;
                                }
                         }
                         catch(Exception ex)
                         {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Device not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                               });
                         }

                        reset.close();
                        conn.close();
                        rowTenDevice = new ArrayList<RowTenDevice>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < DeviceName.size(); j++) {
                            RowTenDevice item = new RowTenDevice(DeviceName.get(j));
                            Log.w("Data:","D"+j+" : "+DeviceName.get(j));
                            rowTenDevice.add(item);
                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                                Log.w("Data:","E1");
                                adapter = new BindTenDeviceBaseAdapter(BindTenGPS.this, rowTenDevice);
                                Log.w("Data:","E2");
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                Log.w("Data:","E3");

                                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                                        // When user changed the Text
                                        BindTenGPS.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
                                    }

                                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                            int arg3) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                                    }
                                });
                                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(
                                            AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int position, long arg3) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(BindTenGPS.this, ShowGPS.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("DeviceList", rowTenDevice.get(position).getDeviceName());

                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }

                                });
                                Log.w("Data:","E4");
                           }
                       });

                        } catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.w("Error connection","shyam" + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        this.wait(500);
                        publishProgress(100);
                    }  
                }  
                catch (Exception e)  
                {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
                return null;
            }
            @Override  
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  
            {  
                //set the current progress of the progress dialog  
                progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);  
            }  
            //after executing the code in the thread  
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
            {  
                //close the progress dialog  
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //initialize the View  
                //setContentView(R.layout.list1_main);  
            }
        }
}
```

---

**BaseAdapter**

```
public class BindTenDeviceBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    List<RowTenDevice> rowTenDevice;
    List<RowTenDevice> arrayList; //temporary list to store filtered values.
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public BindTenDeviceBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowTenDevice> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowTenDevice = items;
        this.arrayList = items;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTenDevice;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayList.indexOf(getItem(position));

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tendevice, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTenDevice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTenDevice);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        RowTenDevice rowItem = (RowTenDevice) getItem(position);

        holder.txtTenDevice.setText(rowItem.getDeviceName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Filter filter = new Filter() {

             @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      arrayList = (List<RowTenDevice>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                      notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                List<RowTenDevice> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<RowTenDevice>();

                if (rowTenDevice == null) {
                    rowTenDevice = new ArrayList<RowTenDevice>(arrayList); // saves the original data in rowTenDevice
                }
                 if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                     // set the Original result to return  
                     results.count = rowTenDevice.size();
                     results.values = rowTenDevice;
                 } else {
                     constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                     for (int i = 0; i < rowTenDevice.size(); i++) {
                         RowTenDevice data = rowTenDevice.get(i);
                         if(data.getDeviceName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                             FilteredArrList.add(data);
                         }
                     }
                     // set the Filtered result to return
                     results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                     results.values = FilteredArrList;
                 }
                 return results;
             }

    };
        return filter;

    }
}
```

---

**RowTenDevice**

```
public class RowTenDevice {
    private String devicename;
    public RowTenDevice(String devicename) {
        this.devicename = devicename;
    }
    public String getDeviceName() {
        return devicename;
    }
    public void setDeviceName(String devicename) {
        this.devicename = devicename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all that code? Terible! And your problem has nothing to do with the next activity. Your only problem is that in on item click listener the value for position goes wrong. Or the value for .get(position).

Comment: okay..so what i have to do..?

Comment: Post minimal code that demonstrates the problem. Why do you bother us with async tasks, databases and run on ui threads? It would be good for your self too to make a new activity with a simple listview and adapter and filter method that demonstrates the problem. If you would do that you would probably find the solution soon.

Comment: Now first check if the value for position goes wrong or the value for .get(position).

Comment: okay will check that one..and sorry for unnecessary codes.

Comment: use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0/raw/10aa5bc585d97596485bdc714fb8e13b199fff3a/MatchableArrayAdapter.java) generic adapter

Comment: @pskink will check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onItemClick you are using rowTenDevice.get(position).getDeviceName(). This causes the problem. You need filtered item so create a public method in adapter to get arrayList.get(position).getDeviceName(). As arrayList is filtered list, it will give you required result.

Use following code:-

Replace line :- intent.putExtra("DeviceList", rowTenDevice.get(position).getDeviceName());

With

intent.putExtra("DeviceList", ((RowTenDevice)adapter.getItem(position)).getDeviceName());

Comment: what happens when i dont search anything..at that time the get(position).getDeviceName() will differ right..?at that time i have to use rowTenDevice.get(position).getDeviceName() right..?how to achieve this one..?

Comment: No need as initially arrayList = rowTenDevice right. List is showing always arrayList item, so using arrayList to retrieve correct item, your code will work fine.

Comment: can u please tell me what i exactly i have to change..?i mean what code i have to add in adapter.?